# Cloud Firestore Update multiple fields in a doc

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The documentation for updating a document reference with Cloud Firestore shows how to update a single field:
`const res = await cityRef.update({capital: true});`

(https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data)

What if I want to update multiple fields of the document from the body of a PUT request?

For example, if my `request.body` is

```
{
    name: "Chicago"
    capital: true
}
```

Is there someway to update the doc in a single call, such as `cityRef.update(request.body}`?

Answer (score 2):

You can either use:

```js
cityRef.update({
    name: "Chicago"
    capital: true
})
```

or

```js
cityRef.set({
    name: "Chicago"
    capital: true
}, { merge: true })
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to [update](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#update) multiple fields in a Firestore document, you need to format your request using `field, value`, `field, value`, `field, value`...

You can use the `.update` to achieve your goal. Something like:

```
[...] cityRef.update({
    "name", “Chicago”, // field, value
    "capital, "true" // field, value
})
```

should do the trick. You will need to add the details in the `[...]`